# Comic book that was released in the 80s

Tags: story-identification, comics, books

I am trying to find out the name of a couple of science fiction comic books that think were released in the 1980s. They were full colour and contained warfare between all kinds of aliens and humans. The fighting scenes were very gruesome and gory with guns and swords, there were robot-like bikers (medieval looking), they may have been robots or alines/humans in robo suits, there was also some naked female aliens.

These were books not magazines or comics they would be like a modern day graphic novel in size. The artist style was sort of like 2000AD.

I know this is a tall order but any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book is called *Delirius*.

[@Paul's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51026/31936) about the Heavy Metal magazine pointed me to Metal Hurlant (May 1978 Cover), which pointed me to the artist Philippe Druillet which pointed me to Lone Sloane and finally to the book *Delirius*.

[image: Delirius]

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible you are thinking of the magazine [Heavy Metal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_%28magazine%29)? It was in full color, has a lot of gruesome violence, naked people and aliens, etc. Sometimes it was fantasy type and sometimes science fiction type. Its initial run was 1977-1987.

As confirmed by the querent the answer is *Delirius* by Lone Sloane:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'd already ruled that one out. I remember the battles were very gruesome with guns and swords. The bikers may have been robots or aliens/humans in robo suits. These were books not magazines or comics they would be like a modern day graphic novel in size.

Comment: You should probably add all that information to the main post.

Comment: The book is called: Lone Sloane - Delirius

@Paul your answer about the Heavy Metal, pointed me to Metal Hurlant to Philippe Druillet to Lone Sloane and finally to Delirius (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QtDxzVASRg)

Thanks

Comment: @user23395 You can answer you own question if you found the answer, then a day later I think you can select it as answered! Please do (helps with sorting answered vs. unanswered questions)

Comment: Lone Sloane from Pilote... NICE!  That's a good one.  Though when it comes to Pilote comics I've always been more of a Valérian & Laureline fan =]

Answer (score 2):

Could this possibly be *Camelot 3000*?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camelot_3000

Similarities:

- gruesomely drawn battle scenes, with swords cleaving aliens in two
- aliens with blasters vs. modern-day knights with swords
- Morgan Le Fay and some other females drawn sexy (not sure about any aliens though)

Answer (score 2):

Could you be looking for [Walt Simonson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Simonson)'s graphic novel **Star Slammers**? It was the first  major work by the artist and writer who later became better known for his seminal run on Thor.

[image]

The original volume was published in 1983, and featured battles between human governments, mercenaries, and aliens. There are robots and humans in armor, although I'm not sure about the biker angle. I also seem to recall that the violence was a little stylized, as is the artist's style.

Five more issues of the story were published in the nineties, but the original graphic novel is self-contained.